How do you disable an audio device on chrome OS
I have a room full of ChromeOS boxes. We are using a usb audio device for connecting headsets but chrome os keeps switching the default audio device to the built-in audio whenever a user logs out. Is there any way to completely disable the built-in audio to stop it flipping back?
